# Rails Migration generating Div instead of table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, data-migration

I am new to rails and I've been following a tutorial on youtube but it appears my [migration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/voJNt.png) isn't working as expected. The migration command was supposed to generate a table database but it appears I am getting my friends' [view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rruGT.png) List database in div and paragraphs. Please what can I do to correct this? Thank you

The data migration code

```rb
class CreateFriends < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    create_table :friends do |t|
      t.string :first_name
      t.string :last_name
      t.string :email
      t.string :phone
      t.string :twitter

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you upload the content of create friends migration file at `db/migrate/202208..._create_friends.rb`

Answer (score 0):

Your migration file should look like this:

```
class CreateFriends < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0] 

  def change 
    create_table :friends do |t| 
        t.string :first_name 
        t.string :last_name 
        t.string :email 
        t.string :phone 
        t.string :twitter

        t.timestamps
    end
  end
```

Assuming it does, it looks fine, we need to see the results of your db:migrate in the console and it wouldn't hurt to show us how you are trying to display the information.  I assume this is the friends list for twitter tutorial from codemy.com  I have done this tutorial myself.

Comment: Yeah, You are right. The friends list for twitter tutorial from codemy.com . I got lost at the point where I didn't see what looks like a table tag in my friends index file

Comment: The index.html.erb file in the friends folder looks like this: <p style="color: green"><%= notice %></p>

<h1>Friends List</h1>

<div id="friends">
  <% @friends.each do |friend|%>
    <%= render friend %>
    <p>
      <%= link_to "Show this friend", friend %>
    </p>
  <% end %>
</div>

<%= link_to "New friend", new_friend_path %>
 Whereas in the tutorial, the index.html.erb file in the friends folder is a table element <table>----</table> I don't know if you understand what I'm trying to say